# What does «the fieri of the effect» mean?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology

What does «the fieri of the effect» mean, in the context of metaphysics/ontology?

I've tried using several dictionaries, but the either got strange meanings, or no results at all...

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From what source?

Comment: It can be *in fieri* (becoming) ? See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_argument)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"In fieri" (in becoming) was a phrase frequently used by the scholastic philosophers. E.g. [here](http://www.logicmuseum.com/wiki/Authors/Thomas_Aquinas/metaphysics/liber5#lib5l1n13).

"He [Aristotle] says that all of the foregoing senses have something in common inasmuch as that is said to be a principle which comes first (1) either with reference to a thing’s being (as the first part of a thing is said to be a principle) or (2) with reference to its coming to be [*in fieri*] (as the first mover is said to be a principle) or with reference to the knowing of it".